# Oracle Sql time out exception when update operation is done throught JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm trying to update a table using the following query in java.

```
update cp set process_name=?  where userid=?
```

?1 = login
?2 = 1234

userid is primary key(number). process_name is varchar2(20).
when running the above query using the sql developer, operation is performed successfully.

But when using java JDBC connection, sql time out exception is thrown and stating the user cancelled the operation. Timeout set is 3 minutes and i don't think this operation requires 3 minutes. since running the query in sqldeveloper takes ony one second.

How should i handle this?

Comment: Is it possible that some other session(s) have locked the row in question and your timeout comes from waiting on the lock?

Comment: right, did you rollback or commit the changes in SQL Developer?